# linux command tail hangs on large file, what is the alternative?

Tags: tail

This

```
 tail -n 1217060 input.sql > /disk2/mysql_dump/output.sql
```

is not writing to the output file. After couple of days, does this mean it's still seeking to the nth line?
Is there a more efficient alternative to this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

i can't imagine anything being any better at this than `tail`

Answer (score 4):

you could use `dd`

```
dd if=input.sql of=output.sql skip=1217060 bs=1
```

should work. Assuming ascii-encoding, because otherwise the offset might be wrong.

**UPDATE:** sorry, I just understood that you want to have the last 1217060 bytes of the file. then you have to calculate the offset yourself. `du input.sql` should give you the size of the file. That amount minus 1217060 should give you the `skip`offset you want to use.

Comment: I want last 1217060 lines, not bytes, of the file

Comment: Sorry, then I propose to try the solution indicated by Gangadhar.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, when I wanted to split a big file (6,666,206 rows) into 10 chunks of roughly the same size (while excluding the first line). For the first nine files, I used a construct like this:

```
head -n 670001 rather_big_file.csv | tail -n 670000 > chunk_1.csv
head -n 1340001 rather_big_file.csv | tail -n 670000 > chunk_2.csv
(...)
head -n 6030001 rather_big_file.csv | tail -n 670000 > chunk_9.csv
```

Each of them took a few seconds to process. But for 10th file, I tried

```
tail -n 636205 > chunk_10.csv
```

which didn't come back; just like described in the original problem.

**But then**, I tried the same construct as for the first nine files, i. e.:

```
head -n 6666206 rather_big_file.csv | tail -n 636205 > chunk_10.csv
```

and returned the desired file after a few seconds.
I have no idea *why* this worked, but it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Is it not possible to split the input files to multiple files before you do this? At some point even tail will take a while to process the file. This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/392156/using-head-or-tail-on-huge-text-file-19-gb)  might be something you can try.

Answer (score 0):

really need more background to why you do this... but potentially you can improve this by tailing and appending just the last few lines of a file, as though it were a log and appending the new stuff to your output file.

tail -f source.sql >> target.sql

can you give more detail? are you using cron in conjunction with this command? why would you want to read then dump so much data? most databases have a dump command...

Answer (score 0):

`tail` has some strange inefficiency when reading files directly.  If you pipe the file to `tail` it is vastly faster on very large files.

`cat input.sql | tail -1217060 > /disk2/mysql_dump/output.sql`